# Pentalobe Screws alternatives for MacBook Pro Unibody

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hardware, motherboard, unibody

I have a MacBook Pro Unibody mid 2012 15'' with several Pentalobe screws used to attach the Motherboard. Unfortunately, I lost some screws after replacing the Keyboard. While I still have most of them, and the Motherboard doesn't move, I was wondering if I could replace all Pentalobe Screws with some other screws.

I first thought about ordering some extra Pentalobe Screws but I couldn't find a buyer for those specific screws online

Do you know what kind of screws I need to replace the Pentalobe Screws ?

Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: iFixit.com sells replacement parts with screws and kits of screws. you will likely not be able to buy *just* what you need but they seem to have kits of screws (also pentalobe drivers) that cover your Mac and provide (almost) all the replacement screws required.